# How to calculate the difference with the previous row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, summarize

I have a database in PowerBi segmented with dates, which, I group in a summary table using the SUMMARIZE function.

The generated table shows me the total of each month accumulated, but I don't know how to calculate in that same expression the difference with the amount obtained in the previous month.

[image: table]

I'm writing the next DAX expression:

```
items_facturation_history_totals = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        items_facturation_join
        ,Calendar[Month Name]
        ,"Total Prize", SUM(items_facturation_join[invoiced]) 
    )
```

And I'm getting this:

[image: Result]

How can I get the following columns?

Data sample -> [Data sample in CSV](https://rentry.co/o4owg)

[image: waitingresult]

Comment: Please can you paste your sample data as copiable text.

Comment: Added in a CSV format @DavidBacci

Comment: Do you use data within the same year (only for 1 calendar year)? I mean is it possible that  it can be added some values from 2022 while summarizing?

Comment: Yeah, the sample that I have now its only from 2023 january to march. But the real dataset maybe is more wide.

Comment: I didn't see the answer - you didn't refer to me. Ok, so you need no have not only a month name but a year number as well e,g dec 22, jan 23 etc, right?

Comment: yeah sorry, I've change it to show month & " " & year -> january 2023...